# Why does the same code/hardware misses data from serial port on different computers? C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, ftdi

I wrote a windows form application code that reads data from serial port and writes it to a text file. The code works beautifully in my main computer. However, the same code does not work properly on my laptop. I am communicating with an external microcontroller at baudrate 3Mbps. I am using FTDI chip which can handle this baudrate. Both computers has .NET framework version 4.5. Also if I lower the baudrate to 1.5Mbps code works on my laptop.

Is there other hardware limitations that I don't know?

Comment: without the code it is difficult to tell where the problem might be. How do you choose the name of the port? is it the same at your main computer and you laptop?

Comment: Since it is the same code for both computers, I thought there was no need for code. It is kind a large code. I check for available ports on my computer then select the port with dropdown menu. In my main computer COM4 is the port. On my laptop it is COM20.

Comment: "However, the same code does not work properly on my laptop." this is a little crude description of the problem. What does it exactly mean "not work properly"?

Comment: @MongZhu  My code waits until certain number of bytes are received from external device. If the bytes are not received in defined time, application asks the same data from external MCU again. The code which runs on my laptop stuck at this stage. I am expecting 65536 bytes but I am getting approximately 64000 bytes. If I wait for 1-2minutes it sometimes gets correct number of data. Code does not run as smoothly as it runs on my desktop.

Comment: Could be environmental, aka your computer, hardware, cable, could be your code, its hard to draw any conclusions

Comment: "Doesn't work on other PCs" is a very common issue. Default settings, unexperienced assumptions, lack of deep IT expertise, etc. If you suspect a code you have to post one. "Not working" is not a professional problem description either. What is not working?

Comment: *"I am expecting 65536 bytes but I am getting approximately 64000"* - how do you receive the data? Please show relevant piece of code, ideally in the form of [mcve]. What are the data? Are they send periodically of by request?

Comment: "Also if I lower the baudrate to 1.5Mbps code works on my laptop" -- Proper operation with a lower baudrate could be indicative of taxing the I/O capabilities of the system. Check for buffer overrun if you think you're losing data.

Comment: Is the COM port properly initialized by the code (baud rate, parity, stop bit, …)? Could be by chance correct by default on one computer, not on the other one.